# Using pipeline for two models

Tags: python, pipeline, knn

I am trying to use pipeline, for implementing two classifiers together. For this I wrote the following code:

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()),('dt',DecisionTreeClassifier())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
parameters = [{'knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 50)}]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.values.ravel(),
test_size=0.3, random_state=65)
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)
```

Pipeline worked fine, while I was using Knn method, however when I used Decision tree classifier, following error occurred:

TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'KNeighborsClassifier()' (type <class'sklearn.neighbors._classification.KNeighborsClassifier'>) doesn't.

How can I add multiple models in a pipeline with different parameters for different models.

Answer (score 0):

Every Pipeline step is secuential, so if you are puttting a `KNN` and a `DTC` just afterwards, you are trying to make a `DTC` with the output of the `KNN`.

I think that you are trying to make a custom `Ensemble` model. Check [VotingClassiffier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) to make a custom `Ensemble`, but I think that the Pipeline object can only see one `RegressorMixIn` in its steps, so this should do the trick:

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('regressor', VotingClassifier(estimators=[
                          ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()), 
                          ('dt',DecisionTreeClassifier())]))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```